# JQGrid how to search with comma as decimal separator

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, decimal

I'm using default navigation searching in JQgrid version 4.6.0 and I'm facing this problem.

In Italy we use `,` as the decimal separator but if I try to search numbers with `,` in them they are recognized as strings. I created a function to replace `,` with `.` when I get a JSON Object

```html
function getValue(cell) {
    value = val[0];*/
    value = cell;
    value = value.replace(',','.');
    parseFloat(value);
    return value;
}
```

and with colmodel formatter I will replace `.` with `,` to let users see the correct decimal separator for their country

```html
function format_cell(cellvalue, options, rowValue) {
if (cellvalue === undefined) return;

var user_language = globalTranslates["user_language"];

if (existIn(user_language, "it")) {
    return cellvalue.replace(".", ",");
}
else if (existIn(user_language, "fr")) {
    return cellvalue.replace(".", ",");
}
else if (existIn(user_language, "es")) {
    return cellvalue.replace(".", ",");
}
else {
    return cellvalue;
}
}
```

With this `,` searching is allowed as float and you can search using decimal separator `.`.

I want to know if there is a method to search with `,` as a decimal separator or if someway I can replace a user's input (so if he uses `,` I can replace it with `.`) before search starts.

My idea is to catch before search event and change value in input using replace, I looked in documentations but I can't find any method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The original poster answered this themselves in an edit to the question. I've moved it here.

```
jQuery("#" + table_id).jqGrid('navGrid', "#" + div_page_id, {
    edit: false,
    add: false,
    del: true,
},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {
        onSearch: function () {
            var postData = $("#" + table_id).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData'),
                coltosearch = postData.searchField;
                searchstring = postData.searchString;

            if (coltosearch === "searchfield") {
                if (existIn(searchstring, ',')) {
                    searchstring = searchstring.replace(',', '.');
                    postData.searchString = searchstring;
                }
            }
        },
    }
);
```